# How to get each double element from scala Iterator[(Double, Double)]

Tags: scala

I am struggling with a basic question on Scala.

I have created a case class in Scala. This case class is being populated by a file using map below. It is working.

But when i am trying to get individual element from yield i am not sure how to extract it.

```
case class PBDivi(
 val country : String,
 val PB : Double,
 val Diviyield : Double)

 val PB = io.Source.fromFile(PBConfFile,"UTF-8").getLines.map(_.split(",")).map {p =>
 val country = p(0)
 val PB = p(1).toDouble
 val Diviyield = p(2).toDouble

 PBDivi(country,PB,Diviyield)
 }                           

    val country = "UK"                                //> country  : String = UK
val a = for (i <- PB; if i.country == country ) yield (i.PB,i.Diviyield)
                                                  //> a  : Iterator[(Double, Double)] = non-empty iterator
val b = a.toList.head                             //> b  : (Double, Double) = (2.5,0.025)
```

As you can see b is (Double:Double). How can i get 2.5 and 0.025 separately.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Thanks zerkms. So has it become a tuple now ? Sorry i am quite new on scala.

Comment: It looks like `b` is a tuple already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options. Here are a few:

```
val b = a.toList.head
val (x, y) = b
val z = b._1; val w = b._2
for ((k, l) <- a) println(s"$k: $l")
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for coming back but val w = b._2 wasn't working. It was failing for null pointer exception. I am not sure if it down to Iterator.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for coming back but val w = b._2 wasn't working. It was failing for null pointer exception. I am not sure if it down to Iterator.

Comment: @user3341078 I can't reproduce your code because I lack the file that is read, but it makes no sense for `val w = b._2` to fail, unless `val z = b._1` failed as well, since `b`  is a `val`, not a `def`. If it were a `def` then, yes, the iterator would run the first time and fail the second. But as long as `b` is not `null` -- such as in your example -- it shouldn't fail.

Answer (score 4):

You can bind `val`s from a tuple like so:

```
val (pb, diviyield) = a.toList.head
```

Or you could get two lists using `unzip`:

```
val (pbs, diviyields) = a.toList.unzip
```

You could then append or interleave the lists, or whatever it is that you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

A side note to pattern matching and unzip as already mentioned in @MattPutnam answer, in order to obtain the head (or first) item that holds a predicate in a collection, consider

```
val a = PB.collectFirst { case v if v.country == "UK" => (v.PB,v.Diviyield) }
```

which delivers an `Option[(Double,Double)]`. Then

```
val (pb, div) = a.getOrElse( (0,0) )
```

where zero is the default value for the case `PB` did not include any entry that fulfilled the condition.

In this approach we halt the iteration once a first hit is reached; in case no solution is found, we deliver default values (well-defined).